# Cannot retrieve products from Google Play store with Fovea purchase plugin

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I'm using the [Fovea.cc purchase plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/) for an Android Cordova app.  The plugin initializes, but cannot find my in-app purchase products - I get the same "Product could not be found" error I would if the product didn't exist or if the app was not published.  I'm looking for more troubleshooting steps.

Here's the relevant code, which is called on app launch:

```
store.register({
    id: "com.ineptech.wn.unlockgame",
    alias: "unlockgame",
    type: store.NON_CONSUMABLE
});
store.ready(function() {
    console.log("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");  // This does get called
});
store.when("unlockgame").approved(function (order) {
    UnlockContent();
    order.finish();
});
store.refresh();
var p = store.get("unlockgame");
popup("Title = " + p.title);  
// this displays "Title = null"
```

And here's the code for the purchase button:

```
store.order("unlockgame");
// Results in "The item you were attempting to purchase 
//    could not be found" error from Play Store
```

Here's what a purchase attempt displays in logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(424): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.IabV3Activity: +80ms
E/Volley(22062): [1009] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase
```

And here's what I've already double-checked:

- "unlockgame" is the correct product ID
- The product is defined in the Play console and is Active
- The app is published and active
- The app is built in release mode and running on a real device
- The device can reach the Play store okay
- My app's license key is stored in res/values/billing_key.xml

What else might be keeping the plugin from getting the products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most probably with your configuration, but first I see is that you're trying to access the product title right after doing store.refresh()

```
store.refresh();
var p = store.get("unlockgame");
```

However, `store.refresh()` method is asynchronous and will just trigger a request to the server. You can monitor changes to your product this way:

```
store.when("unlockgame").updated(function(p) {
    alert("product is " + p.state + ", title is " + p.title);
});
```

Then call:

```
store.refresh();
```

Also check that the product ID on the play console is `com.ineptech.wn.unlockgame`, not just `unlockgame`, and that it's of type `Managed`.

Comment: The product ID is just unlockgame - I entered it that way because I was mimicking your example code: "store.register({ id: 'cc.fovea.purchase.nonconsumable1', ..."  I gather I misinterpreted your example?  I'll test it presently.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists using id: "unlockgame", and the product is managed.  I've reverted to using a different plugin, but if you have any other ideas I'm happy to test them.

Comment: How can i get all active products details (id,name,description) in single function?